# Differentiating between different types of JsValues - Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following code

```
val json : JsValue = Json.parse(jsonMap)
val jsonObj : JsObject = json.as[JsObject]
```

Using `jsonObj.fields` I'm able to get `key, value`pairs in the form of `String, JsValue`. My JSON is nested. Example is below:

```
{ 
  "name": "answer",
  "plural": "answers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
     "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
     "sender": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": true,
        "default": "ASK"
   },
   "read": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    }
   }
}
```

As you can see, some fields, such as `name` have only a single **value**, while others, such as `properties` and `options` have another json object in them. I wanted to know if there is any way to differentiate between the two `JsValues` where one is a clearly a `string` and another is not by using `play.api.libs.json._`

Using `value.isInstanceOf[JsValue]` doesn't work as `JsObject`returns both cases as a JsValue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your end goal for all of this?

Comment: @Tyler Refreshed my page and lost half the question, didn't realize. Please look at edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the types with pattern matching:

```
val raw =
  """
    |{
    |  "nulltest": null,
    |  "name": "answer",
    |  "plural": "answers",
    |  "base": "PersistedModel",
    |  "idInjection": true,
    |  "options": {
    |     "validateUpsert": true
    |  },
    |  "properties": {
    |     "sender": {
    |        "type": "string",
    |        "required": true,
    |        "default": "ASK"
    |   },
    |   "read": {
    |      "type": "boolean",
    |      "required": true,
    |      "default": false
    |    }
    |   }
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val json = Json.parse(raw).as[JsObject]

json.fields.foreach {
  case (key, value) =>
    val `type` = value match {
      case s: JsString => "String"
      case b: JsBoolean => "Boolean"
      case o: JsObject => "Object"
      case n: JsNumber => "Number"
      case a: JsArray => "Array"
      case JsNull => "Null"
    }
    println(s"key: $key type: ${`type`}")
}
```

Outputs:

```
key: nulltest type: Null
key: name type: String
key: plural type: String
key: base type: String
key: idInjection type: Boolean
key: options type: Object
key: properties type: Object
```